# .htaccess - create 404 page without .html ending form

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I would like to create a default 404 page on my website and I know how I can do it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.html
```

But how I can create a special redirect to this page from url: "http://example.com/page-not-found" ?? I searched in Google and here but I find nothing about it.

So finally, when user visit page: http://example.com/test-page and this url is not exist on my website, script should redirect user to page: "http://example.com/page-not-found" and this url should present html code from 404.html file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this in your root directory,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /my_catalog/

# rewritten rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

# not found rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Page-not-found [R=301,L]
```

`Page-not-found` is your supposedly error html file if the incoming request is nor a file neither a directory in your server it will serve page-not-found which is internally rewritten to `page-not-found.html`.

Comment: Now is better but not fine. The redirect is for url: **http://example.com/home/my-domain/domains/example.com/public_html/catalog/page-not-found** Where is a problem?

Comment: where are you using this rule root directory or some other directory?

Comment: here -> public_html/my_catalog/.httaccess

Comment: I've edited my answer please check if it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with `.htaccess` and mod_rewrite.

Modify:

`ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/page-notfound.html`

Then in your `.htaccess` add:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

This is of course, assuming you have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds.

Comment: It doesn't work fine. This script redirect to: http://example.com/page-not-found.html but still ".html" ending exist :/

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite?